# How can I make a page in my android app that shows a list of current comments and rating of my app from play store

Tags: android

I'm learning to make an android app and I have an idea that I think it would be nice if, inside my app, there is a page that just shows a list of current comments and ratings of my app from the play store. Can anyone please tell me how can I do that, or is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: Simply it's not possible. Play Store doesn't allow these kind of data to be accessed programmatically.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know, I really appreciate that!